# What font is this? Trying to find a similar, free Western Style Slab Serif font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-face

I'm curious what font is used for the word "TYPE" in the poster below. Any Ideas?

I already tried such services as [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/), but I still couldn't identify the exact font.

Any free alternative would also suffice. I also like [this font](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFont&code=ROSQ10005090), but it's not cheep. :(

I'm going for a "Western Style" Slab Serif font. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

[http://friendsoftype.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/monstersoftype_06.jpg](http://friendsoftype.com/2011/10/monsters-of-type/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good way to browse free fonts by theme (in this case, fonts tagged 'old western'):

http://www.fontspace.com/category/old+western

5 pages of 'em!

Answer (score 1):

How does this compare to what you want? The font is Sancreek, and I believe it's pretty close to what you want.

[image: Sancreek]

This one's similar, but still, not so similar. ;)

[image: Ewert]

**Both are available for free via Google Web Fonts: http://www.google.com/webfonts#ReviewPlace:refine/Collection:Sancreek|Ewert**

**EDIT:** And as for some free Slab serif fonts, You can go look at [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however I'm thinking that's comming on a bit strong. Especially the last one. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted is custom lettering (rather than a font) created by Ty Wilkins. He originally created this for the site Friends of Type.

http://friendsoftype.com/2011/10/monsters-of-type

Comment: Funnily, the creator answered that question more than a year later to a question by the asker of this question. Not that this invalidates this answer.